Binding to NSManagedObject properties and @State properties
I'm making a 1RM calculator in SwiftUI. Its model is an NSManagedObject called 'LiftEvent' that has two key properties:
extension LiftEvent {
    var eventID: String {
        uuid ?? ""
    }

    var eventCreationDate: Date {
        date ?? .now
    }

    var eventLift: Lift {
        if let lift = lift {
            return lift
        } else {
            if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
                let newLift = Lift(context: context)
                return newLift
            } else {
                fatalError("Managed Object Context is nil.")
            }
        }
    }

    var eventLiftName: String {
        get { lift?.liftName ?? "None" }
    }

    var eventLocalizedLiftName: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(eventLiftName, tableName: "liftLogModel", comment: "")
    }

    var eventFormulaName: String {
        formula?.formulaName ?? "None"
    }

    var eventReps: String {
        get { String(describing: repetitions ?? 0) }
        set { repetitions = NSNumber(value: Double(newValue) ?? 0) }
    }

    var eventWeight: String {
        get { String(describing: weightLifted ?? 0) }
        set { weightLifted = NSNumber(value: Double(newValue) ?? 0) }
    }

    var eventWeightUnit: WeightUnit {
        get {
            if let rawValue = weightUnit {
                return WeightUnit(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .kilograms
            }
            return .kilograms
        }
        set {
            weightUnit = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    static var example: LiftEvent {
        let controller = DataController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = controller.container.viewContext

        let lift = controller.defaultLift()
        let liftEvent = LiftEvent(context: viewContext)
        liftEvent.setValue(NSUUID().uuidString, forKey: "uuid")

        liftEvent.date = .now

        lift?.addToLiftEvent(liftEvent)

        return liftEvent
    }
}

Here's what the `LiftEvent' looks like:

The 'eventReps' and 'eventWeight' are used to calculate a result called 'oneRepMax'. I don't store the 'oneRepMax' value after it's been calculated. I calculate it at runtime whenever needed.
func calculateOneRepMax(weight: Double, reps: Int, formula: String) -> Double {
    // Calculates the oneRepMax and returns the result as a Double
    }


In my CalculatorView, I want the 'oneRepMax' value to be calculated and displayed as the user types.
struct CalculatorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var liftEvent: LiftEvent
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context

    @State var units: String = "kg"
    @State private var oneRepMax: String = "0.0"

    private let weightCharacterLimit = 3
    private let repsCharacterLimit = 2
    
    let calculator = Calculator()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {

                    // This text view should display the calculated 'oneRepMax' value
                    Text(String(format: "%.1f", calculator.calculateOneRepMax(weight: Double(liftEvent.eventWeight) ?? 0, reps: Int(liftEvent.eventReps) ?? 0, formula: UserDefaults.formulaName())))
                        .id(oneRepMax) // Add id to force view update

                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            HStack() {
                                TextField("Weight", text: $liftEvent.eventWeight)
                                    .onChange(of: liftEvent.eventWeight) { _, newValue in
                                        if liftEvent.eventWeight.count > weightCharacterLimit {
                                            liftEvent.eventWeight = String(liftEvent.eventWeight.prefix(weightCharacterLimit))
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                        VStack {
                            Text("Reps")

                            TextField("Reps", text: $liftEvent.eventReps)
                                .onChange(of: liftEvent.eventReps) { _, newValue in
                                    if liftEvent.eventReps.count > repsCharacterLimit {
                                        liftEvent.eventReps = String(liftEvent.eventReps.prefix(repsCharacterLimit))
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showPercentages) {
                        PercentagesView()
                            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar(content: CalculatorViewToolbar.init)
        }
    }
}

Update 1
I have this class DataController: ObservableObject that handles all things Core Data. When a new LiftEvent' is created, it assigns it to @Published var selectedLiftEvent: LiftEvent?`:
@main
struct OneMaxApp: App {
    @StateObject var dataController = DataController()
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    init() {
        _ = dataController.newLiftEvent // creates a new event and assigns it to '@Published var selectedLiftEvent: LiftEvent?' in DataController
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if let newLiftEvent = dataController.selectedLiftEvent {
                CalculatorView(liftEvent: newLiftEvent)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                    .environmentObject(dataController)
            }
        }
    }
}

A new liftEvent is created in the init() and assigned to @Published var selectedLiftEvent: LiftEvent? in DataController. I'm passing that into CalculatorView(liftEvent: newLiftEvent) which is the root view.
One problem is that in the Preview, the Text view that should be displaying the result of the calculation doesn't change as I type in 'weightLifted' and 'repetitions' values.
The second problem is that when I run it in the simulator, I just get a blank white screen because selectedLiftEvent is nil.
What am I doing wrong?

Note, you should move the let calculator = Calculator() outside the body of the view.
Did you declare a class LiftEvent: ObservableObject{...} and have in your parent view
@StateObject private var liftEvent = LiftEvent() that you then pass to your CalculatorView?

To achieve this you need to learn Binding and Text/TextField's formatter:. Also you need to remove the .id() and onChange both are non-standard for data flow.

@workingdogsupportUkraine, I moved let calculator = Calculator() out of the body. LiftEvent is an NSManagedObject which conforms to ObservableObject by default so I didn't declare it. I updated my question to show how I'm trying to pass a new LiftEvent' to my CalculatorView`. Thanks for the help.

try making @Published var eventWeight: Double instead of a String computed property.
Since you don't want to show the code for your LiftEvent, I assume that weightLifted
is part of it, but in the code that you show you don't change that value, which in terms does
not update the computed property, which does not update the view.
Note, you can also use TextField(..., value: ...) that takes a value directly.

I'm not sure why you're saying "you don't want to show the code for your LiftEvent". That's the first code at the top in 'extension LiftEvent'. It's all there. I'm not using 'NSManagedObject' subclasses. I'm using the computed properties in the extension so I am only unwrapping the optionals in one place in my codebase rather than all over the place when I'm dealing with a 'LiftEvent' object. I made them Strings so views can simply display them and that way I'm not doing conversions to Strings in my views. I added a picture of the `LiftEvent' attributes if that helps.

Sorry, my bad, you have the LiftEvent code.
